# How to allow http method OPTIONS from any Origin with S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cors

I'm trying to do some tests and need to have a file on S3 that will be requested first with the `OPTIONS` method. The request will come from various different origins so I need to allow `OPTIONS` from any origin.

This is the error I get on `curl` when I use `-X OPTIONS`, if I don't use that it works fine:

```
<Error><Code>AccessForbidden</Code><Message>CORSResponse: This CORS request is not allowed. This is usually because the evalution of Origin, request method / Access-Control-Request-Method or Access-Control-Request-Headers are not whitelisted by the resource's CORS spec.</Message><Method>GET</Method><ResourceType>OBJECT</ResourceType><RequestId></RequestId><HostId></HostId></Error>
```

This is my config for CORS right now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedOrigin>http://*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedOrigin>https://*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <ExposeHeader>Access-Control-Allow-Origin</ExposeHeader>
    <AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

I even tried putting cloudfront in front of it and allowing `OPTIONS` there but it didn't help.

What should I change?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the curl request you used? please add that to your question also. Only `<AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>` is needed. Remove the other two. Also I would say for now test with `AllowedHeader` as `*`

Comment: I think `AllowedHeader` as * made it work. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in my comments earlier, please change

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedOrigin>http://*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedOrigin>https://*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <ExposeHeader>Access-Control-Allow-Origin</ExposeHeader>
    <AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

to

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <ExposeHeader>Access-Control-Allow-Origin</ExposeHeader>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

That should solve the issue

Comment: The `AllowedHeader` with `*` is the only change I made and that seemed to have fixed it. The answer you left here doesn't have that.

Comment: The other two with `http` and `https` should also not be needed, please check. Have updated the answer